# Different std in pandas vs numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

The standard deviation differs between pandas and numpy. Why and which one is the correct one? (the relative difference is 3.5% which should not come from rounding, this is high in my opinion).

**Example**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

a='''0.057411
0.024367
 0.021247
-0.001809
-0.010874
-0.035845
0.001663
0.043282
0.004433
-0.007242
0.029294
0.023699
0.049654
0.034422
-0.005380'''


df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(a.strip()), delim_whitespace=True, header=None)

df.std()==np.std(df) # False
df.std() # 0.025801
np.std(df) # 0.024926

(0.024926 - 0.025801) / 0.024926 # 3.5% relative difference
```

I use these versions:

```
pandas '0.14.0'
numpy '1.8.1'
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

In a nutshell, neither is "incorrect". Pandas uses the [unbiased estimator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation) (`N-1` in the denominator), whereas Numpy by default does not.

To make them behave the same, pass `ddof=1` to [`numpy.std()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html).

For further discussion, see

- [Population variance and sample variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Population_variance_and_sample_variance).

Comment: yes, in fact df.std()==np.std(df, ddof=1) is True! Therefore the question now becomes which estimator is better :-), just kidding...

Comment: For the record, people considering using `df.std()` and `np.std(ddof=1)` interchangeably should also be aware of another difference between the two: `np.std` returns `nan` if there are any missing values whereas `df.std` returns the standard deviation of the non-missing values.  If you want to ignore nans use `np.nanstd()`.

Comment: This implies that df.std != df.values.std() which I did not expect at all. This seems pretty confusing.

Answer (score 9):

For `pandas` to performed the same as `numpy`, you can pass in the `ddof=0` parameter, so `df.std(ddof=0)`.

This short video explains quite well why `n-1` might be preferred for samples. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cn0skMJ2F3c