# Why do np.std(X) and X.std() return different values?

Tags: pandas, numpy, statistics, standard-deviation

I am trying to calculate normalized scores for my dataset using mean normalization. When I write `(X - np.mean(X))/np.std(X)`, it gives me different score than doing `((X - X.mean())/X.std()`.

Problem seems to be coming from calculation of standard deviation. `X.std()` returns one values for standard deviation and `np.std()` returns different values for standardization. Why is this happening?

Comment: What is `X`? (e.g. Pandas DataFrame, xarray DataArray etc)

Comment: It's a dataframe. I got it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Pandas uses the unbiased estimator (N-1 in the denominator), whereas
>   Numpy by default does not.
>
> To make them behave the same, pass `ddof=1` to `numpy.std()`.

[Different std in pandas vs numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24984178/different-std-in-pandas-vs-numpy)

Comment: Thank you. It gives the same answer now.

Comment: if it solved the issue and you are satisified with this answer , please @Matt, accept it and close the question.